# Autoplay when "A" key pressed

Tags: javascript, html, audio, addeventlistener, autoplay

I would like to autoplay content when user presses a key

This is my code:

```js
var music = document.querySelector("#music");
music.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 65) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  document.querySelector("#music").click();
}})
```

```html
<audio id="music" autoplay loop controls>
    <source src="Music1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source src="Msic1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

This code doesn't work. Can you guys help me? Thanks!

Comment: "This code doesn't work" is usually not a sufficient description of the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `click` use `play`, and you can just use `music` since you already declared it. Also, you need to add the eventlistener to `document` not the audio element.

```
var music = document.querySelector("#music");
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 65) {
        event.preventDefault();
        music.play()
    }
})
```

Comment: I am sorry but this does not work

Comment: @ThomasGiudici I updated my answer, I realized what the problem was. You have to add the event listener to `document` not `music`.